# Fisher's test on 2x10 contingency (expected value <6 in >20% of cell) - Solve R workspace error, OR suggest alternative statistical test?

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio

I have a 2x10 contingency. Unfortunately, 6 cells have an expected value of less than 5, and therefore I can't use Pearson Chi sq test.

I tried to use the Fisher's test in R (`fisher.test()`, which if I understand correctly automatically does a Freeman-Halton extension), but I don't think my computer can handle the volume of calculation.

This is the error I would get:

```
Error in fisher.test(x$size, y$gender, workspace = 2e+08) : 
  FEXACT error 7(location). LDSTP=18716400 is too small for this problem,
  (pastp=328.023, ipn_0:=ipoin[itp=120337]=176553, stp[ipn_0]=318.699).
Increase workspace or consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE'
```

Tried to increase the workspace to 2e9, and got this error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb
```

Would a Chi square test with a Yates' correction deal with the issue? Even then, I can't seem to force R to do a Yates correction on my calculation for some reason - `chisq.test(x$size, y$gender, correct=T)`. The converse, with `correct=F`, works.

Any suggested solutions? Or alternative tests I can use?

Thank you!

Comment: If the values in the table are so large that is a lack of available memory for the calculation.  Can you use the "simulate.p.value = TRUE" option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this example:

```
set.seed(111)
value = rnbinom(1000,mu=69,size=1)
size = cut(value,10)
gender = rep(c("M","F"),each=500)
table(gender,size)

gender (-0.466,46.6] (46.6,93.2] (93.2,140] (140,186] (186,233] (233,280]
     F           244         107         67        42        17        11
     M           255         127         64        28        11         8
      size
gender (280,326] (326,373] (373,419] (419,466]
     F         7         4         0         1
     M         4         2         1         0


fisher.test(gender, size)
Error in fisher.test(gender, size) : 
  FEXACT error 7(location). LDSTP=18480 is too small for this problem,
  (pastp=81.1067, ipn_0:=ipoin[itp=68]=79, stp[ipn_0]=80.6036).
Increase workspace or consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE'
```

And like you said, chisq test with correction:

```
chisq.test(gender,size)$p.value
[1] 0.3452619
chisq.test(gender,size,correct=TRUE)$p.value
[1] 0.3452619
```

And there's a good reason:

> correct: a logical indicating whether to apply continuity correction
>             when computing the test statistic for 2 by 2 tables

You can either use the `simulate.p.value = TRUE` as `Dave2e` pointed out, and in this case it's more or less ok because I simulated under the null, where there's no difference between the groups:

```
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on
    2000 replicates)

data:  gender and size
p-value = 0.3393
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Which is similar to basically a chisquare test with simulation of the distribution:

```
library(coin)
chisq_test(table(gender,size),distribution = approximate(nresample = 10000))

    Approximative Pearson Chi-Squared Test

data:  size by gender (F, M)
chi-squared = 10.065, p-value = 0.3263
```

If your categories are ordered you can try linear-by-linear association, check more out [here](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_09.html).